# I found an old earth ground with #12 wire, should it be changed after a service upgrade?

Tags: electrical, grounding, neutral, grounding-and-bonding

About 10 years ago we had a new meter-main installed upgrading to 200A service from 100A at a new service entrance location (closer to the street) for a 1951 daylight ranch house.  At the time they ran a new earth ground (#6, I think?) to at least one location.

Recently I found an old #12 earth ground connected to a rod on the opposite side of the house from service entrance.  I tested it with a current clamp with only 0.001 A is flowing, so far so good.  Who knows if there are any other grounds around that I've not yet discovered.

What would be best, and why?

- Leave it as is?
- Disconnect it?
- Run a bigger ground to this newly discovered earth ground?

Comment: You might consider finding where the other end of the wire goes.  You have a sensitive current clamp to be able to read that low of current.

Comment: @Gil, it goes into the garage and then into a wall...so except that its clearly a ground, I'm not sure where it goes.  More than likely it ties to some plug somewhere that is grounded, but I can only guess.

Comment: @KJ7LNW -- can you find where it leads? It might be a communications grounding rod...

Comment: Unless it's in the way of some current project, why worry about it?

Comment: @FreeMan, it goes through a 1/2" conduit that will be filled with 3x#8's so would like to ground it to the rest of the system but wasn't sure the best practice here.  The conduit is short through a concrete slab and hard to replace.  I can see both ends of the ground, but the ground through the 1/2" conduit, but it then disappears under a silplate and into an existing wall.

Comment: @KJ7LNW that would be _very_ good info to edit into your question so that people can better understand the situation.  I'm not the guy to answer this, but someone like TPE will know if you answer all the questions asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate grounds are allowed when they originate from the same service panel.

In this case the least expensive option would be to put the #12 in a box and make a connection with another number 12 or larger and connect to the grounding electrode for the new panel or any other grounded circuit that is grounded #12 or larger.

This has only been code for a few cycles but is acceptable.
If you tied the alternate rod with the #6 wire to the original rod or electrode system or at the panel ( the electrode system is within 5’ of the foundation entrance that would be acceptable as a second electrode). the #12 should be removed from the rod as mentioned.